# Str::transliterate does not exist

Tags: string, updates, laravel-9

On update to Laravel 9, I am facing an error, though the `Str::transliterate` method is not used anywhere in the project.

> Method Illuminate\Support\Str::transliterate does not exist.
> {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method
> Illuminate\Support\Str::transliterate does not exist.

This error should get resolved.